# Custom hits order in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, customization

Working with elastic search, I want to order result hits by the following function:

**(Field A matches count * 40) + (Field B matches count * 30) +
(Field C matches count * 60)**

And order this custom score descendent.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Got a few sample docs + the index mapping? Also, what does `Field A matches count * 40` mean?

Comment: Quantity of matches of the term in field A